# React-webcam not getting added to my react project

Tags: reactjs, npm

I did the following to install react-webcam,

```
sudo npm install -g --save react-webcam
npm WARN react-webcam@3.0.1 requires a peer of react@>=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-webcam@3.0.1 requires a peer of react-dom@>=15.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ react-webcam@3.0.1
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 0.351s
```

but it wasnt added to the dependencies in package.json, So how can I add it to the node modules?

Comment: Have you tried ```npm install --save react-webcam```?

Comment: That worked thanks